# Login trouble in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade

I tried to create a login, after I tried successfully identified,

```
return "Success Login";
```

but when I replace with

```
return Redirect::to('dashboard');
```

always returned to Login page
can you help me ? what's wrong with my code...
here is my code :

route.php

```
Route::get('login',array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'))->before('guest');
Route::post('login',array('uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'))->before('csrf');
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
   Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'panel', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@view_dashboard'));
});
```

AuthController.php

```
class AuthController extends Controller {
public function getLogin(){
    return View::make('users.login');
}

public function postLogin(){
    $rules = array('username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required');
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
        ), false);
    if(!$auth){
        return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors(array(
            'Maaf anda bukan sebagai admin..'
            ));
    }
    //return "Success";
    return Redirect::to('dashboard');
}   
}
```

DashboardController.php

```
class DashboardController extends Controller {

    public function view_dashboard(){
        return View::make('dashboard.view_home_admin');
    }
}
```

view_home_admin.blade.php

```
<h1>Welcome <small>{{ ucwords(Auth::user()->username) }}</small></h1>
```

Comment: Probably a problem with your session not working correctly. Check it is holding sessions correctly

Comment: where can i find the setting session in laravel ? Thx